# Jupyter notebook unvisible folders

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I tried to access my jupyter notebook, but it only shows icons, not the names. Neither can I see or access to the folder / files. I can erase or make new folders and files, but I cannot access those, nor see their names:

[image: Screenshot of file.folder list without names]

I already re-installed anaconda but it still does not work.

How can I see the names and enter folders again?

Comment: You'd need to provide a lot more details here to help others help you. First though I suggest trying a few things first. Did you try any other version of Jupyter that Anaconda may have installed? Did you try JupyterLab? I thought the Anaconda Distribution came with a couple versions of Jupyter? Did you try a different browser? Is OneDrive involved? If that doesn't help you'd need to update your pose with version numbers and what type of system you are on, etc.